# JS test runner html vs production html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, tdd, qunit

**ANSWER**:
    On advice from someone outside of SO: put the html in a view file, and inject that both into your production, and testRunner pages.  problem solved.

**Question below in bold**

Lets say I have a method that will move an element 50px to the left, when clicked by the user.

the function responsible for this is

```
function moveElemLeft($elem, iPxLeft){}
```

In my test script, I have essentially:

```
test("test moves function left via css", 1, function(){
    //get first elem in test fixture.
    var $testFixture = $('#qunit-fixture').children().eq(0);
    var beforeLeft = $testFixture.css('left');
    moveElemLeft($testFixture, 50);
    var afterLeft = $testFixture.css('left');
    equal(beforeLeft-50, afterLeft);
});
```

In my testRunner HTML, I would have something like

```
 <head><script href="test.js" /></head>
    <body>
    <div id="qunit-fixture">
    <div id="testChild" class="absolute no-margins">
    </div></div>
    </body>
```

**----- QUESTION ----**
Isn't there a high chance that my function would run correctly during the test, but not correctly in production, because the html I've written in the test fixture is obviously trivial?  Wouldn't it be better to use the same html that's in production as in my test runner html file?

But to do that, that would mean on the test setup, I would have to copy html from the production html file, into the test runner file.  Is that even possible?  What's best practice here?

Answer (score 0):

> Wouldn't it be better to use the same html that's in production as in my test runner html file?

It would be useful to test that in addition to your unit test.

I wouldn't *replace* a small, self-contained test that demonstrates that the function behaves as expected when run on expected input with such a test though.

> But to do that, that would mean on the test setup, I would have to copy html from the production html file, into the test runner file. Is that even possible? What's best practice here?

Run your tests on the production HTML (or rather, on a separate install of it on a dedicated test server). I'd use something like Selenium to test the entire page in a browser (or collection of browsers) without injecting test code into the page itself.

Comment: So philosophically, treat the html and js layers as separate.  The JS tests test that the js is working as intended, and then use another testing suite (you suggest selenium, or [second choice] embedding the js test code) to ensure that the html works correctly with the js.

Comment: Almost. A mechanized browser can test the entire site - HTML, CSS, JS, server side code, etc.

Comment: That sounds like arguing to just use selenium to test that everything works as expected, and only bother with the pure js unit tests if the js is sufficiently complex, and you want to test that the js logic acts the way you intended.